# Why would a default constraint be missing an index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index-tuning

I have a query that looks at the sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats system view to determine what missing indexes there are for maintenance purposes.  If I remove the filter from the query that limits it to only user tables, I get quite a few records for missing indexes for default constraints.

I don't really know the technical details of how a default constraint works, but I was wondering why it would need an index?  Also, the query seems to want to create the index ON the default constraint itself, which seems weird and I'm not even sure you can do that.

Could this just be a weird artifact of not filtering the query to user tables, or do default constraints actually need indexes?

here's the stored procedure, sorry for the length:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [rs].[MissingIndexes]    Script Date: 2/3/2015 4:25:10 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[rs].[MissingIndexes]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [rs].[MissingIndexes]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

declare @indexstats table 
(
    ID int identity(1,1), 
    DBName varchar(255),
    [object_id] int,
    index_id int,
    Reads int,
    Writes int,
    ReadsPerWrite decimal(12, 3)
)

insert into @indexstats
(
    DBName,
    [object_id],
    index_id,
    Reads,
    Writes,
    ReadsPerWrite
)
select 
    d.name as DBName
    ,s.object_id
    ,s.index_id
    ,s.user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups as Reads
    ,s.user_updates as Writes
    ,case s.user_updates when 0 then 100 
        else (s.user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups * 1.0) /( s.user_updates * 1.0) 
    end as ReadsPerWrite
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s
    inner join sys.databases d
        on s.database_id = d.database_id
where case s.user_updates when 0 then 100 
        else (s.user_seeks + user_scans + user_lookups * 1.0) /( s.user_updates * 1.0) 
    end < 1
    and s.user_updates >= 10000



declare @databases table (ID int identity(1,1), DBName varchar(255))

insert into @databases (DBName)
select distinct
    DBName
from @indexstats

declare @i int, @max int
set @i = 1
select @max = max(ID) from @databases




declare @missingindex table
(
    DBNAme varchar(255),
    TableName varchar(255),
    EqualityColumns varchar(max),
    InequalityColumns varchar(max),
    IncludedColumns varchar(max),
    Impact decimal(14,2),
    CreateStatement varchar(max)
)

while @i < @max
begin

    declare @dbname varchar(255)
    select @dbname = DBName from @databases where ID = @i
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)


    set @sql = ''
    select
        '''''' + @dbname + '''''' as DBName,
        so.name,            
        mid.equality_columns,
        mid.inequality_columns,
        mid.included_columns,       
        (avg_total_user_cost * avg_user_impact)
        * (user_seeks + user_scans) as Impact,
        ''''CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_IndexName ON ''''
            + so.name collate DATABASE_DEFAULT + '''' ( ''''
            + isnull(mid.equality_columns, '''''''')
            + case when mid.inequality_columns is null then ''''''''
                else case when mid.equality_columns is null
                    then ''''''''
                    else '''',''''
                end + mid.inequality_columns
            end + '''' ) ''''
            + case when mid.included_columns is null then ''''''''
                else ''''INCLUDE ('''' + mid.included_columns + '''')''''
            end + '''';'''' as CreateIndexStatement
    from
        ['' + @dbname + ''].sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats as migs
        inner join ['' + @dbname + ''].sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups as mig
            on migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
        inner join ['' + @dbname + ''].sys.dm_db_missing_index_details as mid
            on mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle

        inner join ['' + @dbname + ''].sys.objects so
            on mid.OBJECT_ID = so.OBJECT_ID
    where so.type = ''''U''''
    ''

    insert into @missingindex
    (
        DBNAme,
        TableName,
        EqualityColumns,
        InequalityColumns,
        IncludedColumns,
        Impact,
        CreateStatement
    )
    execute sp_executesql @sql, N''@dbname varchar(255)'', @dbname

    set @i = @i + 1
end






select *
from @missingindex m
order by impact desc, DBName





END
' 
END
```

Comment: You should show us that query. Maybe it just looks for "non-pk constraints"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added

Comment: Try adding `AND mid.database_id = DB_ID(@dbname)` the the WHERE clause.

Comment: @DanGuzman that seems to have done it.